# How to Select a Navigation Property efficiently in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, edmx, navigation-properties

I'm having Three Table

Table #1 : BossEmp

```
SNo     JobID     BossID      EMPID       StartDt
_____________________________________________________
  1        1           6          1       05-20-2016
  2        1           6          2       05-20-2016
  3        2           7          3       06-20-2016
  4        2           7          4       06-20-2016
  5        2           7          5       06-20-2016
```

Table #2 : Emplyee

```
EmpID    EmpName      Gender    DOB           Dep
_________________________________________________________    
    1    Sakthivel     M        12-11-1986    Development
    2    Regina        F        04-03-1989    Development
    3    Samantha      F        12-12-1987    Development
    4    Keerthi       F        08-18-1988    Development
    5    Pranitha      F        11-10-1985    Development
    6    Vijay         M        02-21-1987    Development
    7    Bhavana       F        12-06-1985    Development
```

Table # 3 : Job

```
JobID     Title            Description
__________________________________________
    1     RSI              Description RSI
    2     MSI              Description MSI
```

In Table #1 `BossEMP -> JobID` is a **Foreign Key** from the **Job Table** and `BossEmp -> BossID, EmpID` are a **Foreign Key** from the **Employee Table**.

The EDMX Class Diagram is

[image]

```
BossEmps -> EmpID === Employee -> EmpID
BossEmps1 -> BossID === Employee -> EmpID

BossEmps -> JobID === Job -> JobID
```

Now I Need to Create an Object of a Model

```
Class WorkInfo
{
    public List<Employee> EmpList { get; set; }
    public Job JobInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to Create `List<WorkInfo>`, it should contain only Female.

Kindly assist me how to select Navigation Property efficiently in LINQ C# to construct `List<WorkInfo>`

The Database contains more than 1000K Records.

I tried the following Code:

```
using (var db = new EmployeeEntities()) {
                db.BossEmps.Where(b => b.Employee.Gender == "F").Select(e => new {
                    Emp = new {
                        Name = e.Employee.EmpName,
                        Id = e.Employee.EmpId
                    },
                    JobInfo = new {
                        Name = e.Job.Title,
                        Id = e.Job.JobID
                    }
                }).GroupBy(x => x.JobInfo).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Do you want a List<WorkInfo> with in it a List<Employee>? That doesn't sound right. What have you tried so far? Any code that's not working as you want?

Comment: Wait I will append it...

Comment: Your List<Employee>() in WorkInfo should only be a single instance of the Employee, as you will contain multiple WorkInfo objects, which you can place into a List<WorkInfo>

Comment: @monstertjie_za WorkInfo is denoting the Job, Now I'm having two jobs so I used List<WorkInfo>

Comment: The question is not about SQL query, so why do you include database tables? If you want LINQ to Entities query, then include the involved **entities** and their configuration (if any).

Comment: @IvanStoev - If I did anything wrong Sorry for that. Kindly provide your suggestion for my question please. Because Navigation Property takes long time then a normal call. How could I handle it in a efficient manner ?

Comment: Please include the involved entity model classes (e.g. Employee, Job etc.). And eventually the LINQ query you've tried and is slow, so we can analyze it and suggest you a better one (if any).

Comment: @IRPunch Have you tried my solution, and is it running slow in your instance?

Comment: @IvanStoev I added the EDMX Diagram and Code which I was tried. Kindly give your valuable suggestion how to use the Navigation Property efficiently.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I added the EDMX Diagram and Code which I was tried. Kindly give your valuable suggestion how to use the Navigation Property efficiently

Answer (score 2):

If I got this right you need all the female employees who has same job.
In this case I think you are looking for somethig like this:

```
var workInfo = context.BossEmp.Select(b => new
        {
            EmpList = b.Employes.Where(e => b.EmployeId == e.EmployeId && e.Gendar.Equals("F")),
            Job = b.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(j => b.JobId == j.JobId)
        });
```

This will create collection of objects with properties EmpList and Job. If you need it as List you can use ToList() method.

```
var employees = workInfo.EmpList.ToList();
```

and/or

```
var workInfos = workInfo.toList();
```

Comment: erase the problem  tanx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample I quickly put together for you based on your classes.

This should select all females, with their corresponding Job info and employee info, from the BossEmp collection.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
    }

    public Program()
    {
        var bossEmpCollection = new List<BossEmp>()
        {
            new BossEmp() { SNo = 2, JobID = 1, BossID = 6, EmpID = 2, StartDt = DateTime.Now },
            new BossEmp() { SNo = 1, JobID = 1, BossID = 6, EmpID =  1, StartDt = DateTime.Now }
        };
        var employeeCollection = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() { EmpID = 1, EmpName = "Sakthivel", Gender = 'M', DOB = DateTime.Now, Dep = "Development" },
            new Employee() { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "Regina", Gender = 'F', DOB = DateTime.Now, Dep = "Development" }
        };
        var jobCollection = new List<Job>()
        {
            new Job() { JobID = 1, Title = "RSI", Description = "RSI" }
        };

        var workInfoCollection = from bEmp in bossEmpCollection
                                 join e in employeeCollection on bEmp.EmpID equals e.EmpID
                                 join j in jobCollection on bEmp.JobID equals j.JobID
                                 where e.Gender.Equals('F')
                                 select new WorkInfo() { EmpObject = e, JobInfo = j };

        foreach (var workInfo in workInfoCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Emp Name: {workInfo.EmpObject.EmpName} Work Desc: {workInfo.JobInfo.Description}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class BossEmp
{
    public int SNo { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public int BossID { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDt { get; set; }
}
public class WorkInfo
{
    public Employee EmpObject { get; set; }
    public Job JobInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Dep { get; set; }

}
public class Job
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Using this example, will construct the LINQ into one SQL SELECT statement, and only execute, once you loop through the `workInfoCollection` collection, making, one trip to the DB and back.

Every single time you you access a Navigational Property on a model class, the deferred execution in the background, makes a connection to the DB, and only runs the query for that specific items you are wanting to see, essentially, making more calls to the Database, making this less efficient, in my opinion.

If you run a SQL profiler, you will be able to verify this yourself.

Comment: If I used JOIN means then there is no use of using Navigation Properties. Kindly use the Navigation Property instead of JOINS.

Comment: Are you referring to Entity Framework Navigation properties where deferred execution is taking place? Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Kindly give your answer related to Navigation Property.

Comment: Not quite sure I know what you mean about my answer to Navigational properties?